# Codeception terminal doesn't show any colors (PhpStorm)

Tags: colors, terminal, console, phpstorm, codeception

The Terminal in PhpStorm and any other consols are always without color formatting, when I run my tests. Is that maybe a setting problem from PhpStorm? But when I run my tests in Powershell or cmd, the Test output is colorless too.

This are my settings from the codeception.yml:

```
paths:
tests: tests
output: tests/_output
data: tests/_data
support: tests/_support
envs: tests/_envs
     actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
enabled:
     - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
settings:
     colors: true
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

That's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36233. Not implemented yet, unfortunately. Please give it a vote to move up in a queue and receive notifications on it's progress

Comment: But it already worked not so long ago. I can't belive that their is no solution.